# Filtering by multiple columns

Tags: r, filter

I'm very new to R.  Working with the diamonds dataset, I'm trying to narrow down to the specific color diamond, that has all of the cuts, and has a carat weight greater than 1.0.

I got this far, and know the answer (color J has all of the cuts with carat size > 1.0), but want to code it better.

Current code:

```
agg<-filter(aggregate(carat ~ cut+color, ddat, median),carat>1.0)
```

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first get `median` value for each value of `color` and `cut`. `filter` the `color` which has `all` the median values greater than 1.

```
library(dplyr)

diamonds %>%
  group_by(color, cut) %>%
  summarise(med = median(carat)) %>%
  filter(all(med > 1)) %>%
  pull(color) %>% unique

#[1] J
#Levels: D < E < F < G < H < I < J
```